What's the justification for banning GenAI generated *questions*
I am not asking to change the policy. I don't intend to post such questions, my point is philosophical about what makes questions desirable on this site.
There are many obvious reasons to ban genAI (ChatGPT) based answers, most of all hallucinations.
But what would be the issue with generated questions?
I can see how genAI would not be great for maths or stackoverflow subsites, but philosophy seems to be much more flexible in providing great answers to weak questions.
There can be various strategies to generate great questions, like crawling a bibliography of philosophy publications, copying the abstract into a prompt (jeopardy style) like "write a question about the contents of this publication". Same with SEP article sections and such. This can be further improved by adding rules and guardrails from this site about what questions are on-topic.
Such approaches would generate questions arguably no worse than many human generated questions that people currently fight to the death to keep open, and genAI could  generat questions at very high frequency, about all and any topics.

Yes, I am aware of the section, but I don't see which aspects of it would apply to questions. Possibly plagiarism, though I doubt that to be a significant concern for questions for anyone. Again, I am not asking about whether or how this would be a violation, but what the purpose is of making/keeping it a violation.

For the sake of the argument, each real person would just post as many questions using a single account as allowed.

If someone has a question, they should ask it themself, choosing the specific words they want to use to express themself.
One side effect is that a person who posts a question produced by a language model cannot help clarify what they meant, because they didn't express anything to begin with.
But regardless of whether clarification might be asked for, the point is that I don't want to respond to the output of a language model. I want to answer the question of a person, expressed in their words.

But human askers can also not be forced to clarify anything. Yet people claimed some human generated questions were good enough here because some good answers were possible even without requested clarifications. So why require that from an AI question? It's a good reason I grant, but as long as "needs clarification" is treated the way it has been over the last few weeks, it's not a very strong one (you're the least to blame).

Not all human generated questions are "good enough"  either, and inability to clarify is a legitimate reason to vote to leave a question closed. It's not a matter of forcing; it's a matter of teaching people how to use the site effectively. And current LLMs are not set up to learn that way. I have no theoretical objection to somebody using an llm to help them phrase a question, if they are having trouble figuring out how to pose it, but it still needs to be their question, and they need to be able to help us bring it to a point where worthwhile answers can be posted.

Forbidding llms is a partial defense against post storms. The proposal to limit the number of questions per week would partly address that, but would not prevent answer storms.

Opinion:
Generating questions that nobody is asking does not seem a productive use of the community's time. This basically falls afoul of the standard Stack Exchange guideline (admittedly often ignored) that one is supposed to have made at least some effort to research the question before asking of the community, and the specific guideline here that this stack is for discussing philosophy rather than doing philosophy.
If you want to use an LLM as a tool to generate springpoints for exploration, go for it, but keep it to yourself. If that exploration leaves you with unresolved questions that are within our scope here, ask them. But trying to respond to the near infinite onslaught of semi-coherent output that an LLM can produce is both non productive and a fool's errand.

So that would mean we could also have a close reason "did not make enough own research" for humans generated questions.

On some stacks, that is considered reason to close. On others, it is simply considered a reason to downvote.

This is the key point. It's not about banning people from using LLMs as part of their legitimate questions. It is about banning an endless supply of low-quality output from bot accounts (which may then, in turn, be used for spamming or other malicious purposes).
